# What is the best way to match space-like chars?

Tags: ruby, regex

I thought `[[:space:]]` matches all space-like characters, but "zero width space" is a exception.

```
# normal space
32.chr('UTF-8').match?(/[[:space:]]/) #=> true
# no break space
160.chr('UTF-8').match?(/[[:space:]]/) #=> true
# en space 
8194.chr('UTF-8').match?(/[[:space:]]/) #=> true
# em space
8195.chr('UTF-8').match?(/[[:space:]]/) #=> true
# thin space
8201.chr('UTF-8').match?(/[[:space:]]/) #=> true
# ideographic space
12288.chr('UTF-8').match?(/[[:space:]]/) #=> true
# zero width space
8203.chr('UTF-8').match?(/[[:space:]]/) #=> false
# zero width no break space
65279.chr('UTF-8').match?(/[[:space:]]/) #=> false
```

How can I write a regular expression that matchs all these spaces?

Comment: How about `\s` for any whitespace character?

Comment: A quick google though sounds like `\s` won't match a zero-width space. Other suggestions are along the lines of just subbing by the hex character 200B

Comment: `\p{Line_Break=ZWSpace} = U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE`

Comment: How about `[[:space:]]|\u200B|\uFEFF`?

Comment: This is all the space according to Unicode `[\x{9}-\x{D}\x{1C}-\x{20}\x{85}\x{A0}\x{1680}\x{2000}-\x{200B}\x{200E}-\x{200F}\x{2028}-\x{2029}\x{202F}\x{205F}\x{3000}]` Or, you could use this `[\s\p{White_Space}\p{Pattern_White_Space}\p{Bidi_Class=White_Space}\p{General_Category=Space_Separator}\p{Line_Break=Space}\p{Line_Break=ZWSpace}]`

Comment: I would be surprised if something that has _zero width_ would be matched by `:space`.

Comment: @sln the latter is a very nice solution imo, why don't you make that comment an answer?

Comment: @GaborLengyel any explicit enumeration of characters is a _very bad idea_ while dealing with Unicode. The specification changes _quite often_ and the explicit list of characters will become obsolete in this context like tomorrow morning.

Comment: `/[[:space:]#{8203.chr('UTF-8')}#{65279.chr('UTF-8')}]/` would work.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thank you, it's nice to learn something new every day. I still like the resulting code because it's easy to read, but also understand the risk now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, both zero-width spaces are *not considered to be blank spaces*, but [“Other:Format”](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties) characters.

That corresponds [the specification](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/NamesList.txt), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> for `200B`, it’s entitled as “Format characters.” Since you want to match ZWSP, I do not see any reason to not match *all the format characters*, what could be done with:

```
/\p{Zs}|\p{Cf}/ =~ 65279.chr('UTF-8')
#⇒ 0
```

Please also note, that any explicit enumeration of characters is a *very bad idea* while dealing with Unicode. The specification changes *quite often* and the explicit list of characters will become obsolete in this context like tomorrow morning.

There are two general approaches to deal with this:

- parse consortium specs (e.g. [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) does that to ensure the proper handling of *latest* version of the unicode,)
- use generic “groups” (e.g. `[[:space:]]` or `\p{Zs}`.)

Answer (score 1):

Per request.

Doing a Unicode 9 query from the UCD database, these properties all show up
for space.

Running the regex returns 28 characters.

If you run just a `\s`, 29 characters show up.

However, if you combine them, it yeilds 32 characters.
Which I assume is the complete set of whitespace.

`[\x{9}-\x{D}\x{1C}-\x{20}\x{85}\x{A0}\x{1680}\x{2000}-\x{200‌​B}\x{200E}-\x{200F}\‌​x{2028}-\x{2029}\x{2‌​02F}\x{205F}\x{3000}‌​]`

Or

`[\s\p{White_Space}\p{Pattern_White_Space}\p{Bidi_Class=White‌​_Space}\p{General_Ca‌​tegory=Space_Separat‌​or}\p{Line_Break=Spa‌​ce}\p{Line_Break=ZWS‌​pace}]`

References:

http://www.regexformat.com/scrn8/UCDusage.htm
http://www.regexformat.com/scrn8/Uusage.jpg

Here is the complete list

```
000009    <control-0009>
00000A    <control-000A>
00000B    <control-000B>
00000C    <control-000C>
00000D    <control-000D>
00001C    <control-001C>
00001D    <control-001D>
00001E    <control-001E>
00001F    <control-001F>
000020    SPACE
000085    <control-0085>
0000A0    NO-BREAK SPACE
001680    OGHAM SPACE MARK
002000    EN QUAD
002001    EM QUAD
002002    EN SPACE
002003    EM SPACE
002004    THREE-PER-EM SPACE
002005    FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
002006    SIX-PER-EM SPACE
002007    FIGURE SPACE
002008    PUNCTUATION SPACE
002009    THIN SPACE
00200A    HAIR SPACE
00200B    ZERO WIDTH SPACE
00200E    LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK
00200F    RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK
002028    LINE SEPARATOR
002029    PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
00202F    NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
00205F    MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
003000    IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ while it perfectly works, I would mention that the proposed solution could become obsolete/incorrect at any time.

Comment: @mudasobwa - I use an always up-to-date app to guarantee latest info.

Comment: True, as I said _today_ it perfectly works (btw, your app deals with Unicode9, the up-to-date standard is Unicode10.) I just said that tomorrow it might easily become incorrect.

Comment: @mudasobwa - Unicode 10. Really? I just checked a week ago, and UCD is not available for it yet. It just has some added emoji's but still based on 9. Well, whenever it becomes available, I'll add it.

Comment: I have no clue what have you checked, and who UCD is. I follow _unicode.org specs_: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/NamesList.txt That is why I suggested to parse specs themselves, not to rely on some shitty apps.

Comment: I believe _ICU_  and _Unicode.org_ are now one  and the same. UCD is maintained by ICU. From their page, it appears only Unicode 10 beta is available `ICU 59 upgrades to emoji 5.0 data, together with segmentation and bidi updates from Unicode 10 beta.`

Comment: @mudasobwa - ICU is now part of Unicode.org http://blog.unicode.org/2016/05/icu-joins-unicode-consortium.html

Comment: `ICU will be released under the Unicode open-source license (similar to the previous license), just like the Unicode Character Database and the CLDR data`

Comment: List of shitty Company/Apps using ICU's UCD: ABAS Software, Adobe, Amazon (Kindle), Amdocs, Apache, Appian, Apple, Argonne National Laboratory, Avaya, BAE Systems Geospatial eXploitation Products, BEA, BluePhoenix Solutions, BMC Software, Boost, BroadJump, Business Objects, caris, CERN, CouchDB, Debian Linux, Dell, Eclipse, eBay, EMC Corporation, ESRI, Facebook (HHVM), Firebird RDBMS, FreeBSD, Gentoo Linux, Google, GroundWork Open Source, GTK+, Harman/Becker Automotive Systems GmbH, HP, Hyperion, IBM, Inktomi, Innodata Isogen, Informatica, Intel, Interlogics, IONA, IXOS, Jikes,

Comment: (con't) Library of Congress, LibreOffice, Mathworks, Microsoft, Mozilla, Netezza, Node.js, Oracle (Solaris, Java), Lawson Software, Leica Geosystems GIS & Mapping LLC, Mandrake Linux, OCLC, Progress Software, Python, QNX, Rogue Wave, SAP, SIL, SPSS, Software AG, SuSE, Sybase, Symantec, Teradata (NCR), ToolAware, Trend Micro, Virage, webMethods, Wine, WMS Gaming, XyEnterprise, Yahoo!, Vuo, 
and many others